# Assign multiple Items from a table by making a Group ID selection on a form

Tags: vba, ms-access

I would like to be able to assign multiple items from a table by selecting a group ID from a form, group ID is not the primary key, as there are groups ranging from 5 items up to 10. This is for training courses I have courses listed and grouped by training tiers (Tier A, B, C, D, E, M). Each tier has different counts of training courses. I want to be be able to assign all courses in Tier A (5 courses) by selecting Tier A in a form. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I'm missing something, but this sounds like a weird design.  Are you saying your setup is like this?

```
Field_A
5,25,89
```

If that's the case, you need to insert a function and split on that field, so try it like this.

```
Public Function GetValueFromDelimString(sPackedValue As String, nPos As Long, 
                                        Optional sDelim As String = ",")

Dim sElements() As String

sElements() = Split(sPackedValue, sDelim)
If UBound(sElements) < nPos Then
    GetValueFromDelimString = ""
Else
    GetValueFromDelimString = sElements(nPos)
End If

End Function
```

Does that help?

Comment: It is a weird design...Trying to add a "Tier" combo box with options A,B,C,D,E,M (Group ID for training Tiers) and dependent on selection assign multiple training courses to an individual. Employees in one table / Training courses in another / assigned training in another. Trying to figure out how add pics to my comments to show training table at least, not having luck with that either ...